# python Как можно более корретно оптимизировать повторяюшиеся циклы if

Tags: python, циклы, словари, if

** Как можно более корретно оптимизировать повторяюшиеся циклы if:

```
if high_level:
    dict_base["high_level"] = float(high_level)
if low_level:
    dict_base["low_level"] = float(low_level)
if level_up_1:
    dict_base["level_up_1"] = float(level_up_1)
if level_up_2:
    dict_base["level_up_2"] = float(level_up_2)
if take_profit_pips:
    dict_base["take_profit_pips"] = float(take_profit_pips)
... и тд ...
```

Comment: Если `high_level` равен нулю, вы специально его не присваиваете?

Comment: Если вы храните данные в разрозненных переменных вам мало чем можно помочь. Разве только `locals`, но я такое не проповедую. Нужно больше контекста.

Comment: @almaz, пожалуйста, поясните, какую задачу вы решаете таким образом. И как это должно работать - вы хотите из имен переменных делать ключи словаря и значения при выполнении конкретных условий для каждой из этих переменных? (как-то странно это выглядит)

Answer (score 1):

```
for key, val in dict_base.items():
    dict_base[key] = float(val)
```

Comment: а где здесь проверка условия? И как имя переменной в `key` и в `val` попадает?

Comment: @Сергей, Словарь это набор ключей со значениями. При помощи цикла мы можем по нему пройтись и изменить значение ключа. Сам словарь - автор не показал, видимо поэтому у вас возникают вопросы.

Comment: Я знаю, что такое словарь. Как я вижу, автор хочет из имен переменных делать ключи словаря и значения при выполнении конкретных условий для каждой из этих переменных. Вы же просто все значения во `float` переводите. Давайте контекст дождемся от автора.